# Visual Studio 2010 and .bsc file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, objectbrowser

I'm using an open source Mozilla project in Visual C++ 2010.  The project requires UNIX based build tools and therefore I cannot create a Visual Studio project for it directly.  I must use the command line build files (makefile, configure script, etc) bundled with the project to build the project using cl.exe.  (This is due to the fact that some .h files are generated by the make utilities.)

The problem is, without creating a Visual Studio project, how do I browse through the project source files using say the "F12 Go To Definition" feature available in Visual Studio?  I know I can generate a .bsc file using the /FR compiler option.  But, I also found that the Object Browser in Visual Studio 2010 doesn't seem to support a .bsc file.  When I open a .bsc file directly using Visual Studio 2010, it says "Class not registered, Looking for object with CLSID: {D9B3211D-E57F-4426-AAEF-30A806ADD397}.

How do we use a .bsc file under Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately BSC is not supported anymore for Visual Studio 2010+

More details: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/514470/bsc-files-cannot-be-used