# What does .bsc file actually do in C# Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I don't understand what .bsc file actually do and what it means.I saw some projects they use it.Just curious, What's the advantage of it having a .bsc file in my C# application?

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257436/visual-studio-2010-and-bsc-file

Comment: @Sanket that's for C++.

Comment: I run a search through many large projects but none of them have .bsc files. Pay attention to your question and make it reproducible for others.